# Неверный возврат от GET

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccess: `RewriteRule ^m_admin/user\/(.*?)$ m_admin/user.php?login=$1 [L,QSA]`

php: `$login = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect_db, $_GET['login']); echo $login;`

заходим на `/m_admin/user/iAdmin`

получаем: `iAdmin.php/iAdmin`

Должно быть: `iAdmin`

Comment: Если поставить в htaccess RewriteRule ^m_admin/user/(.*?)$ m_admin/user.php?login=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @GrayHoax то же самое

Comment: @ReinRaus не работает. напрямую всё верно: `http://site.ru/m_admin/user.php?login=iAdmin`

Comment: Тогда так) RewriteRule ^m_admin/user\/(.*?)$ m_admin/user.php\?login=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: @GrayHoax так же